# Graph cycle basis and odd cycle transversal

Tags: graphs

I have a graph $G$ and an its [fundamental cycle basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_basis#Fundamental_cycles) $B$.

The question: is an [odd cycle transversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odd_cycle_transversal) of $B$ an odd cycle transversal of $G$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider the following counterexample. Consider a complete graph $G$ on four vertices $V = \{ v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4 \}$.

Let spanning tree $T$ of this graph be composed of edges $(v_1,v_2), (v_2,v_3), (v_1,v_4)$. Then, the fundamental cycle basis $B$ is composed of cycles: $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$, $(v_1,v_2,v_4)$, and $(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4)$. The basis $B$ has an odd cycle traversal $\{v_2\}$. But $v_2$ does not hit the odd cycle $(v_1,v_3,v_4)$ of graph $G$.

Comment: Ok, your answer is right. I would change the question just a little bit: is there an odd cycle transversal of $B$ that is an odd cycle of $G$? In your example it's $v_{1}$.

Comment: @MarioGiambarioli Pick all the vertices of $G$ in the odd cycle traversal.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment. All the vertices of $G$ are not a minimal odd cycle transversal (when I say "odd cycle transversal" I mean "minimal odd cycle transversal" obviously).

Comment: @MarioGiambarioli In my example $v_1$ is not an odd cycle traversal of $G$ since it does not hit the cycle $(v_2,v_3,v_4)$. Therefore, my answer still holds.